# How to disable openshift dependencies download for NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, openshift

I have set an `openshift` cartridge with `NodeJS`. In my `package.json` I have all the dependencies for my project, which `npm` installs in `node_modules` folder. I have added them to the `.gitignore`, but whenever I push the project, the openshift cartridge download all the dependencies.

How can I disable it?

I tried setting the environmental variable `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION` to `true` as described [here](https://developers.openshift.com/en/node-js-getting-started.html), but it didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't disable the installation of dependencies, unless you don't declare them. If your project depends on certain libraries then openshift needs to install them as much as you do on your local machine.

This means that whenever you [deploy your app](https://developers.openshift.com/en/node-js-dependency-management.html) to openshift the build process performs a `npm install`, which will make it install any missing dependencies to the `node_modules` folder.

Note that doing the opposite of what you are doing and track some dependencies on this folder (`git add node_modules/mydep`) will make your deployment process a [bit faster](https://developers.openshift.com/en/node-js-project-structure.html#node_modules).

Also: What `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION` does is setting whether `devDependencies` are installed or not, this means that if you are using dependencies which are only local (for development) you should set them in your `package.json` file like so:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "~1.0.0"
},
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, is there a way to modify the build process? I need the modules just for development since I am using `webpack` to create a bundle. What is the best way then to develop with the dependencies and deploy without them?

Comment: Check my edit, you should set it in the `devDependencies` instead of `dependencies`